# Elastic Search: Put continues Streaming log file JSON Data into index

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a file in my local disk which gets the logs of different applications continuously  in a json format .

I would like to put these continuous json data into Elastic Search index.

**How can we put continuous json data into index.**

Any suggestions.

Bunny.